# C Sharp Stored procedure Timeout on second run

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2012

I am calling a stored procedure via C sharp and for some strange reason it timeouts on the second run.

The code to call Stored procedure:

```
  private void LoadData()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_LoadData);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_LoadDataComplete);

        Busy.IsBusy = true;
        Busy.BusyContent = "Loading Data";
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void bw_LoadData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Logic.GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spGetUserData", con);
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID", uid));




          //Timeouts here on the second run
     SqlDataReader readUserData = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (readUserData.Read())
            {

                    origname = readUserData[0].ToString();
                    origemail = readUserData[1].ToString();
                    origcontact = readUserData[2].ToString();
                    origadd1 = readUserData[3].ToString();
                    origadd2 = readUserData[4].ToString();
                    origstate = readUserData[5].ToString();
                    origcity = readUserData[6].ToString();
                    origzip = readUserData[7].ToString();

                    origcountry = readUserData[8].ToString();


            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            e.Result = "OK";


    }
    void bw_LoadDataComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        Busy.IsBusy = false;
        txtFullName.Text =  origname;
      txtEmail.Text  = origemail ;
         txtContact.Text= origcontact;
         txtAdd1.Text= origadd1;
       txtAdd2.Text=  origadd2 ;
        txtState.Text=  origstate;
         txtCity.Text= origcity;
       txtZip.Text =  origzip;
       cboCountry.SelectedItem = origcountry;

    }
```

First Method call during Window load Event.. Works as expected.

```
       private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();

    }
```

Second Method Call in which the timeout occurs.

```
    void bw_ChangeEmailComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.Result.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            Busy.IsBusy = false;
          MessageBox.Show("The Email Address was changed successfully", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);


        }
        else
        {
            Busy.IsBusy = false;
            MessageBox.Show("An Unexpected Error occured or email already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);



        }
        LoadData();


    }
```

and finnaly the stored procedure

```
          Create Proc [dbo].[spGetUserData]
         @UID varchar(50)
         AS
         Select FullName,Email,Contact,Address1,Address2,State,City,Zip,Country,SubDate,SID
         FROM Users
         Where UID = @UID
```

**UPDATE**

Still not working after trying this and also manually disposing data reader

```
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Logic.GetConnectionString()))
            {

                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spGetUserData", con))
                {
                    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID", uid));



                    con.Open();
                    using (var readUserData = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readUserData.Read())
                        {

                                origname = readUserData[0].ToString();
                                origemail = readUserData[1].ToString();
                                origcontact = readUserData[2].ToString();
                                origadd1 = readUserData[3].ToString();
                                origadd2 = readUserData[4].ToString();
                                origstate = readUserData[5].ToString();
                                origcity = readUserData[6].ToString();
                                origzip = readUserData[7].ToString();

                                origcountry = readUserData[8].ToString();


                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dispose your DataReader, `readUserData`.

Put it in a `using` statement:

```
using (var readUserData = com.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (readUserData.Read())
        ...
}
```

(Use `using` for your SqlConnection too-- `using` is strictly better than manually calling `Close()` and/or `Dispose()`.)

Comment: Ouch... you're passing the DataReader to another thread.  That's not OK.  Remove the `Invoke`, or copy the data to a custom object, and pass the custom object to `Invoke`.

Comment: I completely removed Invoke and it's all working in single thread but still getting Timeout..updated the question yet again to show what i did..

Comment: A background worker should not access GUI elements, try the second approach (Invoke with a POCO object)

Comment: i completely removed all the things and just make the datareader execute not even read data from it.. still timed out :/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.. apparently i learned that bad things happen when u don't rollback transactions on Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code so that your connections, commands, readers, etc... get closed or disposed of automatically. See example below.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(--Conn String Here--)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Set Conn Properties Here
        Conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        } // Reader automatically disposed here
    }
} // Conn automatically closed here
```